# Ajax vs window.location help me understand

Tags: javascript, html

Recently I was messing around with a search bar in html that takes in an input, and I add it as the last parameter in the URL I want to go to. I then change to this new URL using window.location.assign(newUrl). This in turn will make a GET request to my server which is making a GET request to an api I'm using. Is there a reason that this is bad? I've been told that it is hacky and I should be using Ajax, could someone explain why this isn't a good approach?

```
<input type="search" id="searchBar" placeholder="Search for your location">

<button onclick="handleSearchRequest()">Search</button>

<script>
    function handleSearchRequest() {
        var searchInput = document.getElementById("searchBar").value;
        window.location.assign("http://localhost:8080/weather/" + searchInput)
        alert("Successfully requested your weather information")
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to load whole of page if using window-location
=> You need to reload the search bar time after time
and with Ajax you just need to load the necessary part of page
=> Something you just need to update the data and dont need to change the page's components